# Is it possible to print in acrobat pro with a custom file name?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

For example, I’ve got an interactive pdf with custom fields. One of them is document number.

I can create a button that prints a pdf (to a file) but the question is if its possible to print it with a custom name( in my case , document number).
I know how to copy field value to a string but I don’t know how to “paste it” if Acrobat prompts me for the files name while printing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, using the according `printParams` for printing.

Creating PostScript or PDF would not go via printer, but accomplished via `saveAs()`.

For finding the suitable syntax for your application, see the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of [the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/documentation.html).